# Java - PostgreSQL - DAO is not registering in the database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I'm having a little problem in DAO of a Java application I'm doing. I wonder if I'm doing everything right or if I missed something.

My opinion is that the String sql is too long or poorly formatted. I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the other classes and tables, so I will not put them in that topic. Below is the code for the database and DAO.

DAO code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import Leilao.*;
import Banco.Banco;

public class LeilaoDAO {

    public boolean cadastro(LancesLeilao LL){
        boolean r = false;

        java.sql.Date sqlinicio = new Date(LL.getLeilao().getAbertura().getTime());
        java.sql.Date sqlencerramento = new Date(LL.getLeilao().getEncerramento().getTime());

        Connection conn = Banco.getConexao();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        String sql = "WITH ven_key AS"
        +"(INSERT INTO leilao (descricao, inicio, fim, aberto) VALUES (?, ?, ?, true) RETURNING id),"
        +"item_key AS"
        +"(INSERT INTO item (nome, descricao) VALUES (?, ?) RETURNING id),"
        +"il_key AS "
        +"(INSERT INTO itens_leilao(item_id, leilao_id) "
        +"SELECT item_key.id, ven_key.id FROM item_key, ven_key)"
        +"INSERT INTO lances_leilao (leilao_id, item_id, participante_id, valor)"
        +"SELECT ven_key.id, item_key.id, 0 , numeric '?' "
        +"FROM ven_key, item_key";

        try{
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            pstmt.setString(1, LL.getLeilao().getDescricao());
            pstmt.setDate(2, sqlinicio);
            pstmt.setDate(3, sqlencerramento);
            pstmt.setString(4, LL.getItem().getNome());
            pstmt.setString(5,LL.getItem().getDescricao());
            pstmt.setDouble(6, LL.getValor());

            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            r = true;
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(LeilaoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally{
            Banco.closeConexao(conn, null, pstmt, null);
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Database code:

```
  CREATE TABLE participante
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(56) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  senha character varying(96) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT participante_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT participante_email_key UNIQUE (email)
);


CREATE TABLE admin
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(56) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  senha character varying(96) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT admin_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT admin_email_key UNIQUE (email)
);

CREATE TABLE leilao
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  descricao character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  inicio date NOT NULL,
  fim date NOT NULL,
  aberto boolean NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT leilao_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE item
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nome character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  descricao character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT item_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE itens_leilao
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  item_id integer NOT NULL,
  leilao_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT itens_leilao_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT itens_leilao_item_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
    REFERENCES item (id),
  CONSTRAINT itens_leilao_leilao_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (leilao_id)
    REFERENCES leilao (id)
);

CREATE TABLE lances_leilao
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  leilao_id integer NOT NULL,
  item_id integer NOT NULL,
  participante_id integer NOT NULL,
  valor numeric NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT lances_leilao_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT lances_leilao_leilao_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (leilao_id)
    REFERENCES leilao (id),
  CONSTRAINT lances_leilao_item_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
    REFERENCES item (id),
  CONSTRAINT lances_leilao_participante_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (participante_id)
    REFERENCES participante (id)
);
```

Query used in DAO for example:

```
 WITH ven_key AS
        (INSERT INTO leilao (descricao, inicio, fim, aberto) VALUES ('something', current_date, current_date, true) RETURNING id),
      item_key AS
        (INSERT INTO item (nome, descricao) VALUES ('thing', 'something') RETURNING id),
      il_key AS 
        (INSERT INTO itens_leilao(item_id, leilao_id) 
        SELECT item_key.id, ven_key.id FROM item_key, ven_key)
 INSERT INTO lances_leilao (leilao_id, item_id, participante_id, valor)
   SELECT ven_key.id, item_key.id, 0 , numeric '10000' 
   FROM ven_key, item_key;
```

Comment: what error is thrown when running this code?

Comment: This is the point, the code is not throwing any errors.

Comment: It simply does not insert anything into the database. But using the query I wrote at the end of this topic, it inserts into the database without any problem.

Comment: Another opinion, may be the "Numeric" type of Postgres, I'm trying to insert as "Double", but I do not know if this could interfere in some way and nor did I find another primitive type to replace.

Comment: If you know a way to debug to find possible mistakes, tell me that I will do the tests.

Comment: Is there is something *wrong* with the actual SQL then it should throw an Exception, but if there error is logical/business or you are just missing transactions then it will not.

Comment: What is the code of `Banco.getConexao` and `Banco.closeConexao`, does it by any chance disable auto commit and do you forget to commit before closing?